# How to include HTML elements in a dialog window without having them appear on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jquery UI dialog to display messages in a web application. The only way that I know how to display elements in the dialog(a button and a text area in my case) is to add them to the main HTML page and make a call to the div containing the elements I want to display, like this:

**HTML being added to my index.html**

```
    <!-- Message box -->
    <div id="messageBox">
        <div id="confirmErrorContainer">
            <span id="messageText"></span>
            <textarea class="skuValidationElement" id="skuValidationList" rows="10" cols="10"></textarea>
            <div id="buttonContainer">
                <button class="confirmDialogElement skuValidationDialogElement"
                    id="confirmError">Okay</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Opening the dialog via JQuery**

`$("#messageBox").dialog("open");`

I currently hide the elements initially, show them when I open the dialog, and the hide them when the "OK" button is clicked. There has to be an easier way to do this though. Could I store the html in a separate file and then load it?

Comment: `$('<div>everything can be dialog</div>').dialog()` ??? I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/8BF6N/

Comment: More or less `$("#messageBox").load('external.html').dialog("open");` but then again why would you want that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add `display:none` to your css:

```
#messageBox {
  display: none;
}
```

You don't have to display the elements when you call `.dialog()` as it copies the html it finds using the selector you provide to the function. You also don't have to hide it again after the dialog was closed.

Answer (score 0):

You just need Confirmation box:-

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#messageBox" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      buttons: {
        "Close": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "ok": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method, so in your example:

```
$("#messageBox").load(path_to_external_html).dialog("open");
```

And have the messageBox div as an empty div ready to receive the external html.

Answer (score -1):

How about the following CSS?

```
#messageBox textarea,
#messageBox button {
  display: none;
}

.dialog #messageBox textarea,
.dialog #messageBox button {
  display: block;
}
```

So initially the page will not display the textarea and button. Once the dialog is open, it will change the display of the elements. The `dialog` class would need to be adapted to the class name applied when the dialog is open.